# AWS AutoScaling Incremental tagging instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I'm setting up an auto-scaling group and to dynamically tag instances, is it possible to auto-increment name tag?

for eg:-
**Key**: Name **Value**: Instance-1
**Key**: Name **Value**: Instance-2
.
.
.
**Key**: Name **Value**: Instance-N

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it possible. But not directly using any AWS functionality.

You have to embed a function where in as the instance is launched by AutoScaling Group a notification (AWS SNS) is triggered and is stored in SQS.

You will have to use a Program/Script which runs on a server and keeps a constant watch on the SQS, get the latest notification and Information regarding the Instance. Then change the Tag Name of the instance using a incremental functionality.